# reflection of erb variables

Tags: ruby, reflection, erb, puppet

I'm using a puppet template, which does an erb interpretation of the template file.  I'd like to know all the variables available to me, however, there are variables available (e.g., fqdn) that are not listed by any of the reflection methods I'm aware of, specifically, none of these:

```
<% Module.constants.each do |v| %># module constant: <%= v %>
<% end %>
<% Kernel.local_variables.each do |v| %># local variable: <%= v %>
<% end %>
<% Kernel.instance_variables.each do |v| %># instance variable: <%= v %>
<% end %>
<% Module.class_variables.each do |v| %># class variable: <%= v %>
<% end %>
<% Kernel.global_variables.each do |v| %># global variable: <%= v %>
<% end %>
```

Is there an extra reflection method for erb that will reveal these to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["See all client variables"](http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/see-all-client-variables.html) should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know about puppet templates, but if `fqdn` is a local variable, then calling `local_variables` (as in `self.local_variables`) should display it.

Comment: While Kernel.local_variables returns a (small) list of elements, self.local_variables generates an error: Could not find value for 'local_variables'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know as much as I'd like to about erb's built-in means of reflection, but with Puppet, I think the hash returned by `scope.to_hash` is probably what you want. From [the templating reference](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html):

```
<% scope.to_hash.keys.each do |k| -%>
<%= k %>
<% end -%>
```

Alternately, if you just want a one-time look at the variables the agent node supplies, you can run `facter` on the node; that's how Puppet gets all that info in the first place.